# Should I disavow blogs?

Tags: google, disavow-links

I have a retail site who has been hit by a algorithmic change within Penguin recebntly. It is referenced within many blogs in both review and list formats without adding the `nofollow`.

They are personal blogs; their page rank is quite low in general but not the lowest so as to counted as a spam link, and they are genuine (not invented for peddling said site's brand), nor are they paid for, but could easily be detected as such.

Most of these people probably don't even know what HTML is let alone how to make a `nofollow` link.

Taking into account what ohers may say ( http://moz.com/ugc/what-is-an-unnatural-link-an-in-depth-look-at-the-google-quality-guidelines ) this behaviour could easily be seen by Google as:

> Exchanging Goods or Services for Links Or Sending Someone “Free” Product in Exchange for Them Writing About it and Including a Link

Should be I on the safe side and just disavow instantly?

Comment: What makes you think it's the Penguin Algo that affected your rankings and specifically it is these links?

Comment: @JohnConde My search rankings dropped 2 days after the latest penguin update, I lost about 3/4 of my serch queries

Comment: I would not be ready to bet they are the links you mentioned. Perhaps something else? Has anything changed recently? Retail sites are particularly hard to SEO. There may be something that needs to change on your site. Do you have any product pages that can be seen as duplicates for example?

Comment: @closetnoc It happened on the 25th of Oct, I have 2 code commits a couple of days before but both were single line changes within PHP models

Comment: @closetnoc The only other error I have is 57,000 pages that cannot be found but since that error has been persistent since about mid this year (new site, yet to make 301s and clear them) I am not really ready to pin it on that

Comment: @closetnoc Our total indexed pages are higher than ever at about 352,000, though not crazy high

Comment: `@JohnConde My search rankings dropped 2 days after the latest penguin update, I lost about 3/4 of my search queries` I wouldn't call that evidence... and would call that the normal algorithm. Additionally penguin has been nerfed.

Comment: @bybe How no code change do this? I mean literally the only evidence I have of Google throtling my site is that the search query graph in GWT has lost 3/4 of its hits

Comment: Unless your site has engaged in blackhat you should never need to disavow anything...

Comment: @bybe But that would trigger a manual action if they ever thought that wouldn't it?

Comment: manual and even automated penguin hits will send notifications through webmaster tools, the normal algorithm does not. If you've spammed your website on blogs, forums and every other worthless site then yes your likely to received a slap, but again this doesn't mean its penguin and removing links could make matters worse because you could be removing ones that Google hasn't hit you with.

Comment: @bybe I have recieved no notification from Google of penalisation, it is completely silent, infact the site is about to become a Google certified Shop ironically (one more trial day). I have ran backlink scanners and apart from some directory and list sites the only others I can find are ones like this and some articles have mentioned that these links can be frowned upon if they are dofollow

Comment: And how many links does your site have?

Comment: @bybe coming on 22K when I download from GWT

Comment: That doesn't sound like a few directory and list sites...

Comment: @bybe most of them are from blogs, specifically blogspot, like 9,000 of them

Comment: In the comment field or actually within the article... and are they relevant links i.e page about cats to page about cats?

Comment: @bybe I have ones like: http://gwentbirding.blogspot.co.uk/2009/12 /and-whither-weather-is-bound.html

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It sounds like you were in good hands with @bybe who is excellent! Depending on the age of your site, you may have issues with link velocity and quality. I took a look at the page that you provided, it is rather thin and the link text are *here* and *this* which do not add value. If you have 22k links from pages like the one you gave us, it maybe that Google is beginning to be suspicious but not penalizing you. The rate/speed at which sites are link to is an indication to Google which can trim down performance while they check things out. It could bounce back.

Comment: @closetnoc I really hope it is temporary, it is so weird there is nothing to explain it, what's worse is that it is impossible to actually ask Google what the hell is going on, 98% monopoly on the market and you still cannot get support for their service...

Comment: I agree that Google can be more helpful. Their fear is that it will be used against them, but what they forget is to so many of us are honest and just want a good glimpse into what they are thinking. Also, know that GWT is a few days behind and that if there is a notice from Google, it could come later than sooner. I suspect that it could be link related with 22k links, but not necessarily a problem and I would not disavow blogs. I would be looking for poisoned links from a competitor and other negative SEO tactics though. Perhaps a recent (past few months) shift in the link profile?

Comment: @closetnoc I have noticed that on ahrefs the number of referring domains has suddenly gone really high, though not sure what to make of it, need to find out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google does not always inform site owners about penalties. Some will argue, but there is a reason why the Google Webmaster Tools (GWT) lables this option as Manual Penalties. In the beginning that's exactly what that feature was. But now Google has automated several additional penalties but not all. So please do not count on this feature as the definitive proof that you are not penalized.

From what I have seen over the years, there are several reasons why search performance can drop due to links.

- Sudden increase in links makes Google nervous. (temporary)
- Unnatural back linking (repetitive/manipulative).
- High ratio of low quality back links.
- Participating in a back link scheme.
- Negative SEO.
- Toxic back links mostly due to spammy or low quality sites.
  (temporary)

This is just off the top of my head. There may be more I am not considering here.

I suspect you fall into the first and/or last items in this list. In the first case, Google is just being cautious while they reassess you link profile do to a sudden change. In the second case, most of these sites can disappear and change link strategies very quickly allowing for recovery automatically. This is not necessarily a given and should not be relied upon.

If you have a popular topic, the various spammers and content scrapers will take notice and try and bleed off any search success for themselves. This has been going on for may years of course. And while Google is combating this, these tactics still work for a broad spectrum of search engines and sites.

You can use GWT to extract a list of links using *Links to Your Site* and *More*. From there, you should be able to download the links that Google is aware of as a CSV (comma separated value) file. It has been a while since I have done this. You can open this file in any spreadsheet.

I found this excellent list of things to look for here: http://www.audiencebloom.com/2014/01/perform-full-backlink-audit-remove-toxic-links/

- Obviously spammy sites, porn sites, payday loan sites or gambling
  sites
- Sites that are not indexed by Google
- Sites with a virus or malware warning
- Sites that have no Page Rank
- Sites with very new domain names
- Sites with very little traffic
- Link networks
- Sites with an unusually large number of external links
- Irrelevant sites

You can use your spreadsheet to: one, sort by URL, two, code each site according to category. From there you can determine what sites really should be disavowed.

- You can check to see is a site is junk by using the site:example.com
  search option.
- You can check to see if a site is infected or blacklisted by using:
  http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx
- You can check to see if Google thinks a site is safe by using a URL
  like: http://www.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=example.com
- You can check to see if a site has any page rank, is new, or has
  traffic using a URL like:
  www.worthofweb.com/website-value/example.com

For the rest, you may have to risk visiting the site/page to see for yourself what is going on. But do this with some caution of course.

Keep in mind, you want to disavow links from a site in a conservative manner. ***DO NOT*** get too carried away. Just hit the most toxic sites first if at all and see what happens. You will need to use your judgement of course and detach yourself from any emotion you feel.